# Manually edit the clocked time

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I clocked the following job

```
**** 10.Agenda Views
:PROPERTIES:
:Effort:   5:00
:END:
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2019-05-17 Fri 07:58]--[2019-05-17 Fri 09:28] =>  1:30
CLOCK: [2019-05-17 Fri 06:37]--[2019-05-17 Fri 06:57] =>  0:20
CLOCK: [2019-05-16 Thu 20:11]--[2019-05-16 Thu 20:34] =>  0:23
CLOCK: [2019-
 05-16 Thu 09:23]--[2019-05-16 Thu 10:18] =>  0:55
```

:END:

And forgot to clock the other time span .

```
CLOCK: [2019-05-18 Sat 04:50]--[2019-05-18 Sat 19:26] 
CLOCK: [2019-05-17 Fri 20:03]--[2019-05-17 Fri 23:00]
```

Revised them as:

```
**** 10.Agenda Views
:PROPERTIES:
:Effort:   5:00
:END:
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2019-05-18 Sat 04:50]--[2019-05-18 Sat 19:26] 
CLOCK: [2019-05-17 Fri 20:03]--[2019-05-17 Fri 23:00]
CLOCK: [2019-05-17 Fri 07:58]--[2019-05-17 Fri 09:28] =>  1:30
CLOCK: [2019-05-17 Fri 06:37]--[2019-05-17 Fri 06:57] =>  0:20
CLOCK: [2019-05-16 Thu 20:11]--[2019-05-16 Thu 20:34] =>  0:23
CLOCK: [2019-05-16 Thu 09:23]--[2019-05-16 Thu 10:18] =>  0:55
:END:
```

However, the agenda view does not display the updated time-span.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to just place the cursor on that line and press `C-c C-c` then Org mode will calculate the time.